# Matlab and Python produces different results for PCA

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, pca

I am using PCA and I found PCA in sklearn in Python and pca() in Matlab produce different results. Here are the test matrix I am using.

```
a = np.array([[-1,-1], [-2,-1], [-3, -2], [1,1], [2,1], [3,2]])
```

For Python sklearn, I got

```
p = PCA()
print(p.fit_transform(a))

[[-1.38340578  0.2935787 ]
[-2.22189802 -0.25133484]
[-3.6053038   0.04224385]
[ 1.38340578 -0.2935787 ]
[ 2.22189802  0.25133484]
[ 3.6053038  -0.04224385]]
```

For Matlab, I got

```
pca(a', 'Centered', false)

[0.2196    0.5340
0.3526   -0.4571
0.5722    0.0768
-0.2196   -0.5340
-0.3526    0.4571
-0.5722   -0.0768]
```

Why is such difference observed?

---

Thanks for the answer of Dan. The results look quite reasonable now. However if I test with a random matrix, it seems that Matlab and Python are producing results that are not scalar multiple of each other. Why this happens?

```
test matrix a:

[[ 0.36671885  0.77268624  0.94687497]
[ 0.75741855  0.63457672  0.88671836]
[ 0.20818031  0.709373    0.45114135]
[ 0.24488718  0.87400025  0.89382836]
[ 0.16554686  0.74684393  0.08551401]
[ 0.07371664  0.1632872   0.84217978]]
```

Python results:

```
p = PCA()
p.fit_transform(a))

[[ 0.25305509 -0.10189215 -0.11661895]
[ 0.36137036 -0.20480169  0.27455458]
[-0.25638649 -0.02923213 -0.01619661]
[ 0.14741593 -0.12777308 -0.2434731 ]
[-0.6122582  -0.08568121  0.06790961]
[ 0.10680331  0.54938026  0.03382447]]
```

Matlab results:

```
pca(a', 'Centered', false)

0.504156973865138   -0.0808159771243340 -0.107296852182663
0.502756555190181   -0.174432053627297  0.818826939851221
0.329948209311847   0.315668718703861   -0.138813345638127
0.499181592718705   0.0755364557146097  -0.383301081533716
0.232039797509016   0.694464307249012   -0.0436361728092353
0.284905319274925   -0.612706345940607  -0.387190971583757
```

---

Thanks for the help of Dan all through this. In fact I found it's a misuse of Matlab functions. Matlab returns principal components coefficients by default. Using [~, score] = pca(a, 'Centered', true) will get the same results as Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PCA works off Eigen vectors. So long as the vectors are parallel, the magnitude is irrelevant (just a different normalizaton).

In your case, the two are scalar multiples of each other. Try (in MATLAB)

```
Python = [-1.38340578  0.2935787 
          -2.22189802 -0.25133484
          3.6053038   0.04224385
          1.38340578 -0.2935787 
          2.22189802  0.25133484
          3.6053038  -0.04224385]

Matlab = [ 0.2196    0.5340
           0.3526   -0.4571
           0.5722    0.0768
          -0.2196   -0.5340
          -0.3526    0.4571
          -0.5722   -0.0768]
```

Now notice that `B(:,1)*-6.2997` is basically equal to `A(:,1)`. Or put another way

```
A(:,n)./B(:,n)
```

gives you (roughly) the same number for each row. This means the two vectors have the same direction (i.e. they are just scalar multiples of each other) and so you are getting the same principal components.

See here for another example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1183707/118848

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I got same results this time. However if I use a random matrix the results seem not to be scalar multiples of each other. I have put the new test matrix and results in the original question. Do you mind having a look at it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not around MATLAB at the moment but they also might just be in a different order... so if you rearrange the columns of one of the matrices you should be able to get to them being scalar multiples. My guess would be ordering the columns be the size of the eigen values should solve it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I finally figured out the problem.

Comment: @user3451228 please add what you figured out so future readers of this question find the complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's actually misuse of Matlab function (sorry about this). I have updated with this in case anyone need similar information.